# How to map node size in cytoscape RCy3 using setNodeSizeMapping

Tags: r, cytoscape

I am new to Cytoscape and RCy3.
I tried to map the node size to the column cell.number in my node table, but failed.
my code and error message is as shown below:

```
> nodes
    id cell.number    infor
1 1507         688 1507-688
2 1540          20  1540-20
3 1516          10  1516-10
4 1538          10  1538-10
5 root           1     root

> edges
  source target dist
1   root   1516  347
2   root   1507  335
3   root   1538  375
4   root   1540  328

> createNetworkFromDataFrames(nodes,edges)
Loading data...
Applying default style...
Applying preferred layout...
networkSUID 
        252 

> layoutNetwork("force-directed")

> setNodeSizeMapping('cell.number',table.column.values=nodes $ cell.number,mapping.type = "c")
Error: table.column.values and visual.prop.values don't match up.
style.name not specified; updating "default" style.
Error in if (visual.prop.name %in% vp.list) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Does anyone have an idea about that?

Thanks,

Jieqiong

Answer (score 0):

For a continuous mapping, you need to provide at least 2 pairs of values to define the min and max. Currently, you are providing 5 table.column.values and NULL sizes.

In this case you'll want to assign min and max table.column values, e.g., c(1, 688) together with min and max sizes corresponding to those values, e.g., c(10, 60). Try something like this...

```
setNodeSizeMapping('cell.number', c(1,688), c(10,60))
```

Also note that the Default style might not have node dimensions locked, meaning that it is using separate width and height values rather than the combined size value. Simply run this function to lock node dimensions:

```
lockNodeDimensions(TRUE)
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the information. 
If I want to do the node size mapping with a customrized style on a specif layout, I should do : 1. layoutNetwork 2. setNodeSizeMapping 3. setVisualStyle , it that right?

Comment: Order doesn't matter. You can specify the style.name when you setNodeSizeMapping, so that can be done before or after you setVisual Style. And layouts are independent of styles. The layout doesn't "know" about the size of nodes. So, you can layout before or after setting a style and you should end up with the same result.

Comment: Thanks! I have one more question about how to set the edge line length mapping to the distance between source and target nodes. I did: 
` createNetworkFromDataFrames(nodes,edges) 
lockNodeDimensions(TRUE) 
layoutNetwork("forcedirected")
setNodeSizeMapping('cell.number',c(min(nodes$cell.number),max(nodes$cell.number)), c(10,60)) 
` 
Seems each edge line length is equal. As I remember in Cytoscape when I manually choose layout "Prefuse Force Directed Layout" the edge line lenghth maps the distance. Could you please show me how to do it in RCy3?